# How do I improve my solution for resetting files in Git which show as modified but have no changes according to "git diff"?

Tags: bash, git, shell

This *seems* to be working but also is quite horrendously slow and seems a little hacky to me.

```
IFS=$'\n'

for currentFile in $(git status | grep "modified:" | cut -c 14-)
do
    gitDiff=$(git diff "$currentFile")
    gitDiffStr="[$gitDiff]"
    if [ "$gitDiffStr" == "[]" ]
    then
        echo match
        echo git checkout "$currentFile"
        git checkout "$currentFile"
    fi
done
```

The reason I'm doing this is that when moving a bunch of files into Git that should have included many identical files, Git suddenly flagged up thousands of changes.

Upon looking at these files most of them had no changes according to `git diff` and solutions that involved `autocrlf` in `.gitattributes` and `.git/config` did nothing for  me.

**Update and Extra Background**

The reason I'm moving all these files to the folder in Git is that I have access to two repositories that were previously mirrored. One in SVN and the other is this one in Git. The mirror capability no longer exists, but Git is going to be the single repo going forward.

It's also only one commit behind, but the that commit happens to involve big folder with lots of C++ code, some of them libraries. I thought I'd just copy the folder over in 5 minutes, Git would pick up the files that had actually changed and I'm good to commit.

However it looks like some files (mostly third party source code files) were in UTF-8 in SVN.

[image]

But then when I reset the Git file (which should be identical as the two repos were once mirrored). It becomes an ANSI encoded file...

[image]

As I mentioned, these two repos were mirrored, those files should be identical. Is this a quirk moving files between SVN and Git or something else?

Comment: Did you check if there is some difference in the file permissions?

Comment: I tried using `git config core.fileMode false` to no avail. Forgot to mention, sorry!

Comment: Please don't change `core.filemode`.  It's not a setting for you to change at your whim.  It's a cache of how Git has detected that your filesystem works.

Comment: Tell us about your line endings.  Do you use `core.autocrlf`?  Do you use `.gitattributes`?  How are they configured?

Comment: I tried all variations of line endings, nothing changed. I've updated my post with further information.

Comment: I'm not sure how your text editor decides what files are UTF-8 and what are ANSI (the presence of a BOM? something else?), but the most likely explanation is probably because `autocrlf` is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just remove the index?

```
$ rm .git/index
```

This will, of course, discard any changes that you've staged into the index. (Though it's unlikely to end up in a situation where useful work exists only in the index, and not in a working tree or the HEAD commit, it might be worth keeping in mind.)

> git status | grep

You may want to use the `--porcelain` flag when using `git status` in scripts. It will emit a format that is more stable and easier to parse.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that file, what does removing `.git/index` achieve in general terms? I'm looking to keep the modified non-binary files that do actually have changes according to `git diff`, but just get rid of the ones that seem to be "modified" despite showing nothing on `git diff`.

Comment: "what does removing .git/index achieve in general terms?" - It clears git's index (also called cache or staging area).

Comment: "but just get rid of the ones that seem to be "modified" despite showing nothing on git diff" - In your situation, I would make the first order of business to figure out exactly what causes that situation. I know of two possible causes: autocrlf on Windows (which I strongly recommend that you turn off), or filters.

Comment: I did some further investigation and have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the original question, but rather a reference for future googlers looking for the same solution on Windows with powershell (too long to be a comment).

```
cd 'c:\my-repo\'
$gitStatusOutput = git status --porcelain
foreach ($statusOutputLine in $gitStatusOutput) {
    $statusLineArr = $statusOutputLine.split(' ')
    $currentFileStatus = $statusLineArr[1]
    $currentFilePath = $statusLineArr[2]
    if ($currentFileStatus -eq 'M') {
        $gitDiffOutput = git diff "$currentFilePath"
        if ("$gitDiffOutput" -eq "") {
            git checkout "$currentFilePath" --quiet
        }
    }
}
```